# NSIS silent installer returning exit code 1

Tags: installation, nsis, exit, silent-installer

I compile an NSIS script to a .exe install file. I launch the .exe with command line \S silent option.

Installation performs silently as wanted, but there is exit code 1. Exit code 1 corresponds to case with user choosing cancel on the wizard. However, install is successful and mode is silent (no user interaction). Also, where does this exit code comes from, and how to manually enforce an exit code 0?

I have an idea i could do something in .onInstSuccess function, to enforce an exit code 1 if installation is successful.

Also, ExecWait is capturing the exit code into a variable, but has got no 'set' option.

What would you recommend?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Are you saying that a silent installer with a single empty section produces a exit code of 1? If so, please show us how you capture this exit code, and if not, show us some NSIS code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any sample code it is a bit hard to guess what the problem could be!

You can set a specific exit code with `SetErrorLevel`.

As far as ExecWait goes, setting anything makes no sense, when it returns the child process has ended. If you want to use the exit code of a child process all you need is to get it:

```
ExecWait '"c:\foo.exe"' $0
SetErrorLevel $0
```

Comment: when installer is silent, then function .onGuiEnd is not entered. I guess i could be reqson why it does as if user would have cancel the installer. So i have an idea your code sample in function .onInstSuccess could do it... but with no `$` : not catching the true exit code, but enforcing 0. i will try but would like to have your opinion on my interpreteqtion (installer not visiting .onGuiEnd --> exit code 1)

Comment: .onGuiEnd is not executed in a silent installer (No pages are used and no GUI callbacks)